# Magento 2.3 : Get category attribute by store wise

Tags: multistore, magento2.3, category-attribute

I have used below code to get attribute value,

```
$category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');    
$external_url = $category->getData('attribute_code');
```

How to get it by store wise?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how about using CollectionFactory of category?

Comment: I think using it you can filter by store

Answer (score 1):

You can get value store vise from category collection :

```
protected $_storeManager;
protected $catCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $catCollectionFactory,
    $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->catCollectionFactory = $catCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($data);
}

$categories = $this->catCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
foreach ($categories as $category){
    echo $category->getData('attribute_code');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code it's helpfull for you.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->getCollection()->setStoreId('store_id')->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_code');
```